# Drupal AuthCache Conflicts

Tags: drupal, caching

I'm developing a website on EC2 and have the development and live site hosted on the same server (for $'s sake).

What I'm encountering is caching conflicts. Specifically on the dev site I have things that are not intended to be seen by the public yet but because it seems that both sites are using the same APC cache the entries are conflicting, and so the public is seeing things it really shouldn't yet.

The dev environment is a complete copy of the live site just checked out from subversion.

Both sites are available on different domains if it helps tailor the answer.

Any suggestions on how to make sure this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

I've drilled down into the AuthCache code and found that there are many things that can cause a page not to get cached. Among them is `isset($_COOKIE['nocache'])`. This means that I can set $_COOKIE['nocache'] on login in my own module when the request is being performed on the on the dev site.